# Avoid data redundancy in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm tinkering with Prolog and ran into the following problem.
Assume I want to create a little knowledge base about the courses of an university.
I need the following two relation schemes:

```
relation scheme for lecturer: lecturer(Name,Surname)
relation scheme for course:   course(Topic,Lecturer,Date,Location).
```

I have a lecturer, John Doe:

```
lecturer(doe,john).
```

John Doe teaches the complexity class:

```
course(complexity,lecturer(doe,john),monday,roomA).
```

Now I have a redundancy in the information - not good!
Is there any way to achieve something like this:

```
l1 = lecturer(doe,john).

course(complexity,l1,monday,roomA).
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same normalization possibilities as in data bases apply:

`id_firstname_surname(1, john, doe).`

and:

`course_day_room_lecturer(complexity, monday 'A', 1).`

That is, we have introduced a unique ID for each lecturer, and use that to refer to the person.